# encoding returnUrl query string in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, query-string, urlencode, returnurl

I'm trying to pass `ReturnUrl` query string to my login page. I have a partial Login view (kind of like a login box) and a login view. Right now, I have the following line in my partial view:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Login"
                    , "Account"
                    , new { returnUrl=HttpUtility.UrlEncode(
                                      Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]) 
                                      ?? HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.Path)
                           }
                    , FormMethod.Post))
```

When I click on my partial view's submit button(e.g. from 
`http://localhost:12345/Product/1234/Product1`),

I'll get redirected to my login page with the following url:

```
http://localhost:12345/Account/Login?returnUrl=%2FProduct%2F1234%2FProduct1
```

But if I log on, I'll see an http 400 response, because the page is returning to

`http://localhost:12345/Account/%2fProduct%2f1234%2fproduct1`.

Also, if I type in the wrong credentials, I cause the `returnUrl` query string to be encoded again thus every `%` character is converted to `%25` again!

I should mention if I manually type in

`http://localhost:12345/Account/Login?returnUrl=/Product/1234/Product1`

(without encoding) and log in, I'm successfully redirected to the specified path.

I guess I'm missing something obvious. But couldn't find out what.

Thanks.

Comment: isnt the encoding done automatically for you? you don't need to encode it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to encode it when you pass it to `Html.BeginForm()` Just use the value without encoding it as it is encoded by the `TagBuilder` when assigning the value to the `action` attribute of the generated `<form>` element

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(
    "Login", 
    "Account", 
    new { returnUrl= Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] }, 
    FormMethod.Post)) {

    @* form here *@    
}
```

I've removed the null-coalescing operator and `Request.Path` too because if `ReturnUrl` is null, it's not going to matter to the generated url assigned to the `action` attribute (assuming it's an optional parameter in your routing, or an optional property on your ViewModel).

The [relevant source code in `TagBuilder`](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/72551#266517) is (comment mine)

```
private void AppendAttributes(StringBuilder sb) {
    foreach (var attribute in Attributes) { 
        string key = attribute.Key;
        if (String.Equals(key, "id", StringComparison.Ordinal /* case-sensitive */) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute.Value)) { 
            continue; // DevDiv Bugs #227595: don't output empty IDs 
        }

        // ---------------------------------------
        // Value will be HTML attribute encoded by 
        // the Encoder set for the application
        // ---------------------------------------
        string value = HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(attribute.Value); 
        sb.Append(' ')
          .Append(key)
          .Append("=\"")
          .Append(value) 
          .Append('"');
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use this to avoid encoding of your return Url:

```
@Html.Raw([Your Return Url])
```

Hope this helps!

Matt